# menubar primeNG creates a submenu when resizing the screen, how can I remove it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, menubar

I am working with Angular 14 and primeNg and in the menubar where I have the items it creates a second menu with the hamburger.

menubar without resizing:

[image]

resizing the menubar automatically creates a submenu:

[image]

menubar.component.html

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
    <ng-template pTemplate="end">
        <button type="button" pButton label="CERRAR SESION" icon="pi pi-sign-out" (click)="logout()"></button>
    </ng-template>
</p-menubar>
```

menubar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';

import { SidebarService } from '../../services/sidebar.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/auth/services/authentication.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-menubar',
  templateUrl: './menubar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menubar.component.css']
})
export class MenubarComponent implements OnInit {

  items: MenuItem[] = [];

  constructor(private sidebarService: SidebarService, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'EJEMPO',
        icon: 'pi pi-bars',
        command: () => {
          this.sidebarService.visibility = true;
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to remove the submenu from the resize menu.